# Matlab: "grouping mean"

Tags: matlab, statistics

Suppose I have the vectors:

```
 y = [1 1.01 1.02 1.03 2 2.01 2.02 3 3.01 3.02 3.03];
 c = [0 0    0    0    1 1    1    2 2    2    2   ];
```

Is there a vectorized way to get a "grouping mean", that is, the mean value of `y` for each unique value of `c`? (This is a simplified example; I have something similar but the vector size is in the thousands and there are hundreds of values of c)

I can do it in a for-loop, just wondering if it could be vectorized. Here's my for-loop implementation:

```
function [my,mc] = groupmean(y,c)
my = [];
mc = [];
for ci = unique(c)'
    mc(end+1) = ci;
    my(end+1) = mean(y(c==ci));
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer:

```
>> y = [1 1.01 1.02 1.03 2 2.01 2.02 3 3.01 3.02 3.03];
>> c = [0 0    0    0    1 1    1    2 2    2    2   ];
>> groupmeans = accumarray(c'+1,y',[],@mean)
groupmeans =
        1.015
         2.01
        3.015
```

To explain the above: `accumarray` is a bit cryptic, but extremely useful and worth getting to know (and very fast). The first input is a vector (they need to be column vectors, which is why it's `c'` and `y'`) that groups the rows of the second input vector. The elements need to be positive integers (for some reason), which is why I've added 1 to `c'`. The last input is a handle to a function that is applied as an accumulator to each group of the values in y.

Hope that makes sense! If not, `doc accumarray` :)

Comment: cool! thanks! Looks like I could also use the index returned from `unique` as the first argument to accumarray (e.g. if my unique values weren't consecutive integers)

Comment: @JasonS: or use `grp2idx` from the stats toolbox

Comment: Or use consolidator from the file exchange.

Comment: @Jonas: thanks for the suggestion. A rant not directed at you: I hate the way that Mathworks puts useful little functions in ala carte toolboxes. My company can't afford to buy a bunch of floating licenses of toolboxes just so we can use that kind of function; the licensing mechanism is expensive and the licenses don't get released until you close out of the program as a whole. (end rant)

Comment: @JasonS: fortunately, these little functions often can be implemented relatively easily, and there are nice people like `woodchips` that tend to do these things for us and put their code onto the File Exchange.